# How to set proxy in Firefox Webdriver Permanently

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Since I cannot set a proxy from Geckodriver directly, I will change it manually by using

```
from selenium import webdriver


myProxy = "xxxxxxxxx:yyyy"
ip, port = myProxy.split(":")


profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.proxy_type',5)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http','xxxxxxxxx')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port',yyyy)
profile.update_preferences()

driver=webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('http://www.google.co.th')
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
```

I am trying to execute, the firefox has changes into proxy mode

However, when I execute script via Robot Framework, which it also execute via Geckodriver, it doesn't change into proxy.

I need to know the way to permanently change proxy in Geckodriver

Answer (score 2):

With SeleniumLibrary's [Open Browser](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser) keyword you could set any preferences like you would do in your Python script.

For example the following test would open a browser every time with these options:

1. Proxy HTTP port set to 777.
2. Proxy type set to "5".
3. Proxy HTTP "xxxxxxxxx".

---

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Open Browser    http://example.com    Firefox   ff_profile_dir=set_preference("network.proxy_type", "5");set_preference("network.proxy.http", "xxxxxxxxx");set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 777)   # Defining profile using FirefoxProfile mehtods.
    Sleep    1 min    reason=Verify proxy settings manually in the opened browser.
```

Values checked on the Firefox's about:config page during sleep:

[image]

Comment: When I execute via Robot Framework, it cannot executed

Comment: @Parit What does it say? Probably your SeleniumLibrary version is too old, please upgrade to above 4.0.0 preferably to 4.5.0

Comment: I has already upgrade new version of Robot Framework, as well as RIDE Robot Framework. It caught the error that

  File "d:\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Scripts\robot.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robot'

which I had already reinstall, restart laptop and set the environment variable.

Comment: @ParitKittirattanaviwat It would have been enough to upgrade the SeleniumLibrary like: `pip install --upgrade robotframework-seleniumlibrary` or `pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary==4.5.0`.

Comment: @ParitKittirattanaviwat PYTHONPATH and PATH environment variables are correctly set?  If you have reinstalled and it still cannot find it, could mean that it does not know where to find it.

Comment: I am already upgrade by using
pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary==4.5.0

it still got the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220398/discussion-between-parit-kittirattanaviwat-and-bence-kaulics).